# How to authorize by role in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented security config in my Spring Boot app using Spring Security and for checking role access to the endoints by role, I use the following approach:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
public class TestController  {

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public String allAccess() {
        return "Public Content.";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('MODERATOR') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String userAccess() {
        return "User Content.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String adminAccess() {
        return "Admin Board.";
    }
}
```

My questions are:

**1.** Is there another way to check roles in Spring Security? Or should I use this approach with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")` ?

**2.** I use this app with a React frontend app. Then, should I use this annotation? Or, is there any extra annotation ahouls I add to my Controllers?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
```

**Update:** Here is my config where there is a CORS setting:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()

            // other settings
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the [@Secured](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/access/annotation/Secured.html) annotation together with

```
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
```

Which makes it more readable:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
@Secured({"USER","MODERATOR","ADMIN"})
public String userAccess() {
    return "User Content.";
}

@GetMapping("/admin")
@Secured({"ADMIN"})
public String adminAccess() {
    return "Admin Board.";
}
```

You should also consider defining constants for those values:

```
public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ADMIN";
public static final String ROLE_MODERATOR = "MODERATOR";
public static final String ROLE_USER = "USER";

@GetMapping("/user")
@Secured({ROLE_USER,ROLE_MODERATOR,ROLE_ADMIN})
public String userAccess() {
    return "User Content.";
}

@GetMapping("/admin")
@Secured(ROLE_ADMIN)
public String adminAccess() {
    return "Admin Board.";
}
```

If you are allowing CORS from *, why not just disable CORS?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252307/discussion-on-answer-by-bill-mair-how-to-authorize-by-role-in-spring-security); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.